# Pull object from database in views.py

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a function in views.py to retrieve an information from this class:

```
class Vin(models.Model):
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.nom

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 30)
    year = models.CharField (max_length = 4)
    appellation = models.ForeignKey(Appellation)
    photo = models.CharField (max_length = 70)
    quantity = models.IntegerField ()
    released = models.IntegerField()
```

and retrieve it by its attribute "name".

So for instance, if i have a Wine ("chardonnay", 1990, ...) only retrieve chardonnay.

Thanks !

Comment: What about this are you finding difficult, or not covered by the extensive documentation? This is the simplest thing you can do in a model.

Comment: This is covered by the docs really well. You should at least read the Django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Your view function will be called after the user enters a URL that is in your `urls.py`. The url entered may provide you with the additional information you need to query the database and get information on the `Vin` object you need.

If you want a view to just return every `Vin` in your database. Something like this might be helpful for you:

```
def get_vins(request, *args, **kwargs):
    vins = Vin.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True) 
    return render(request, 'somepage.html', {"vins": vins})
```

Your question is really vauge and you should read the django documentation. This is a very basic question that all starters should learn.